# CSS позиционирование на лайтбоксах

Tags: css

Можете подсказать, как на странице https://zigzag.kg/otzyvy/ , при нажатии на картинок, на лайтбоксах, чтобы знак крести ("x") был справа сверху ?

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему нужно переверстать всплывашку. Но если отталкиваться от того что уже есть и ничего не подвёрстывать особо, то к уже имеющемуся селектору дописать три правила для позиционирования:

```
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]), a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus, a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    // Ниже эти самые три правила, выше то, что у вас уже написано и есть в коде.
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    right: 39%;
}
```